# Understanding the equation $|x+1|=x^2 -1$

Tags: analysis

I want to understand the equation

$$|x+1|=x^2 -1$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x^2 - |x+1| - 1 = 0$$

Case $1$:

$$x+1 \geq 0 \Rightarrow x^2 - x-2 = 0$$
$$x_{1,2} = \frac{1}{2} \big( 1\pm \sqrt{1-4\cdot(-2)} \big) = \frac{1}{2}(1\pm3) \Rightarrow x_1 = 2, x_2 = -1$$

Case $2$:

$$x+1 <  0 \Rightarrow x^2 + x = 0 \Rightarrow x_3= 0 \text{, (but doesn't fulfill } x+1 < 0), x_4 = -1$$

$$\Rightarrow L = \{2,-1\}$$

What I don't get is how $x+1 <  0 \Rightarrow x^2 + x = 0$. How do we get $x^2 + x = 0$?

Comment: Why do you think that *'ordinary - differential - equations '* tag is relevant ?

Comment: The answer below explains the $x^2+x$. But note that in case 2 the value -1 is not a solution because you are assuming $x+1<0$. So the only solutions come in case 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x + 1 < 0$ then the initial equation becomes $$\begin{align*} && -(x+1) &= x^2 - 1 \\ &\iff&-x -1 &= x^2 - 1 \\ &\iff& 0 &= x^2 + x\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 3):

Suppose that $x$ satisfies

$$(*) \quad |x+1|=x^2 -1.$$

Then $|x+1|=(x -1)(x+1).$ Hence $|x+1|=|x-1| \cdot |x+1|.$

It is clear that $x=-1$ is a solution of $(*)$. Now we assume that $x \ne -1.$ Then we get $|x-1|=1.$  The last equation has the solutions $x=0$ and $x=2$. But only $x=2$ is a solutions of $(*)$.

Consequence: $(*)$ holds $ \iff x \in \{-1,2\}.$

Answer (score 1):

For $x+1 \geq 0$, $|x+1| = x+1$, and hence the equation reads as:

$$x+1-x^2 +1 = 0 \Rightarrow x^2 -x - 2=0.$$

For $x+1 < 0$, $|x+1| = -(x+1)$, and hence the equation reads as:

$$-(x+1)-x^2 +1 = 0 \Rightarrow x^2 +x=0.$$